# "composer install" invokes post-update-cmd instead of post-install-cmd

Tags: php, composer-php

I have this simple composer.json file. When I run "composer install" I expect it to run post-install-cmd script but nothing happens. If I change it to post-update-cmd it works as expected. Am i missing something? Doesn't it have to run post-install-cmd instead of post-update-cmd?

```
{
    "name": "vendorName/packageName",
    "description": "Some description",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "psr/log": "^1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "$SHELL script.sh"
    }
}
```

Comment: `post-install-cmd: occurs after the install command has been executed with a lock file present.` Do you have a .lock file?

Comment: It doesn't exist the first time I run "composer install". I'm using "composer init" to create composer.json file. I answered no to the question "Would you like to install dependencies now? And because of that I have no composer.lock file until I issue "composer install". Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

The `(pre|post)-update-cmd` is invoked when running `composer install` if you don't have a **lock-file** (`composer.lock`) in your project's root directory.

The `composer install` command is meant to install the dependencies in the lock-file.

If there is no `composer.lock` it will run `composer update` internally to resolve the dependencies and generate the lock-file for you.

From the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i) of the `install` command:

> If there is no composer.lock file, Composer will create one after dependency resolution.